# How to get row with max dot product using MemSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, singlestore, dot-product

First of all, I'll preface this by saying I have minimal experience with SQL.

Anyways, I have a table in MemSQL of the following format:

```
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
| id  |  uuid  | identity | template |
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
| int | string | string   | blob     |
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
```

I am trying to use the MemSQL `DOT_PRODUCT` [feature](https://docs.memsql.com/v6.8/reference/sql-reference/vector-functions/dot_product/) to obtain the `identity` of the template which generates the maximum dot product against a probe vector that I have provided. Note template is a normalized array of floats of fixed length.

My SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT id, identity, MAX(DOT_PRODUCT(template, JSON_ARRAY_PACK('[<probe template here>]'))) 
AS score FROM collection;
```

However, I seem to be experiencing strange behavior, where I am getting inconsistent results (1 out of 10 times that I execute the query I will get a different identity but always the same max score). Additionally, the `identity` is incorrect (see further below).

The result from the query is the following (9 out of 10 times):

```
+----+-------------+------------------+
| id |  identity   |      score       |
+----+-------------+------------------+
|  7 | armstrong_2 | 0.56488848850131 |
+----+-------------+------------------+
```

As a sanity check, I wrote the following SQL statement, expecting for the max to be the same. Note, I am using the exact same probe vector from before:

```
SELECT id, identity, DOT_PRODUCT(template, JSON_ARRAY_PACK('[<same probe template from before>]')) 
AS score FROM collection ORDER BY score DESC;
```

The results are as follows:

```
+----+--------------+--------------------+
| id |   identity   |       score        |
+----+--------------+--------------------+
|  1 | armstrong_1  | 0.56488848850131   |
| 21 | armstrong_1  | 0.56488848850131   |
|  6 | armstrong_1  | 0.56488848850131   |
| 11 | armstrong_1  | 0.56488848850131   |
| 16 | armstrong_1  | 0.56488848850131   |
| 17 | armstrong_2  | 0.534708674997091  |
|  7 | armstrong_2  | 0.534708674997091  |
| 22 | armstrong_2  | 0.534708674997091  |
|  2 | armstrong_2  | 0.534708674997091  |
| 12 | armstrong_2  | 0.534708674997091  |
| 10 | mr_bean_2    | 0.072085081599653  |
| 15 | mr_bean_2    | 0.072085081599653  |
|  5 | mr_bean_2    | 0.072085081599653  |
| 20 | mr_bean_2    | 0.072085081599653  |
| 25 | mr_bean_2    | 0.072085081599653  |
| 14 | mr_bean      | 0.037121964152902  |
|  9 | mr_bean      | 0.037121964152902  |
|  4 | mr_bean      | 0.037121964152902  |
| 19 | mr_bean      | 0.037121964152902  |
| 24 | mr_bean      | 0.037121964152902  |
| 13 | jimmy_carter | -0.011749440804124 |
| 23 | jimmy_carter | -0.011749440804124 |
| 18 | jimmy_carter | -0.011749440804124 |
|  8 | jimmy_carter | -0.011749440804124 |
|  3 | jimmy_carter | -0.011749440804124 |
+----+--------------+--------------------+
```

What is going on? Why is the `MAX` identity from the first query not the same as the max identity (top row) for the second query? Is one / both of my query statements incorrect?

Additionally, when I compute the dot product by hand (without any SQL or MemSQL), I find that `armstrong_1` does indeed produce the highest score of `0.56488848850131`. So why is my first SQL query (with the `MAX` operator) not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not valid SQL:

```
SELECT id, identity, MAX(DOT_PRODUCT(template, JSON_ARRAY_PACK('[<probe template here>]'))) AS score
FROM collection;
```

You have no `GROUP BY` but the query is an aggregation function (due to the `MAX()`.  Then there are two other columns.  This is not valid SQL and it is sad that some databases allow it.

The best approach is `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT id, identity, DOT_PRODUCT(template, JSON_ARRAY_PACK('[<probe template here>]')) AS score
FROM collection
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1;   -- or whatever your database uses to limit to one row
```

Comment: Just a follow up question. I have a second scenario in which I need to obtain the top n unique identities which produced the highest match scores. How can I go about doing that? Looks like I can use the statement from above using the `LIMIT n`, but then would need to somehow only allow unique identities

Comment: @cyrusbehr . . . That would be a different question.  This is specifically about returning a single value.